# D3.js & React.js - How to resize brush when axis change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am using React and D3 for providing an interactive dashboard for data exploration.
The dashboard consists out of **multiple histograms with brushing functionality** and one big chart in the middle.
When brushing is done, the whole data for all elements is filtered (by filter engine).
Problem is: All axis are changing when data is filtered (has to change), but the **brushing size overlays are not changing its size**.
E.g. Example: Before Brush

[image: Example: Before Brush]

I brush in a range between -4% and 12%. After brushing, the axis change to the new range, but the brush overlay does not change the size.

Example: After Brush

[image: Example: After Brush]

The histograms looks like this:

```
export const Histogram = ({
    heightHisto,
    widthHisto,
    dataFiltered,
    dataInternFiltered,
    xValue,
    sumValue,
    xFormat,
    boolLogScale = null,
    ticks = null,
    brushFilterFunc
}) => {
    const innerHeightHisto = heightHisto - marginHistoMini.top - marginHistoMini.bottom;
    const innerWidthHisto = widthHisto - marginHistoMini.left - marginHistoMini.right;
    const brushRef = useRef();
    const xScaleHist = boolLogScale ?
        scaleLog()
            .domain(extent(dataFiltered, xValue))
            .range([0, innerWidthHisto])
            .nice()
        :
        scaleLinear()
            .domain(extent(dataFiltered, xValue))
            .range([0, innerWidthHisto])
            .nice()
        ;

    const binnedData = bin()
        .value(xValue)
        .domain(xScaleHist.domain())
        .thresholds(xScaleHist.ticks(ticks))(dataInternFiltered)
        .map(array => ({
            y: count(array, sumValue),
            x0: array.x0,
            x1: array.x1
        }));

    const yScaleBinned =
        scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, max(binnedData, d => d.y)])
            .range([innerHeightHisto, 0])
            .nice();

    useEffect(() => {
        const brush = brushX().extent([[0, 0], [innerWidthHisto, innerHeightHisto]]);
        brush(select(brushRef.current));
        //brush.on('brush end', (event) => {
        brush.on('end', (event) => {
            const brushing = event.selection && event.selection.map(xScaleHist.invert);
            brushFilterFunc(brushing, xValue);
            if (brushing) {
                setHistRangeFilterLabel(`Filter: ${xFormat(brushing[0])} to ${xFormat(brushing[1])}`)
            } else { setHistRangeFilterLabel(null) };
        });
        //brush.extent(brush.extent());
        //brush.move(select(brushRef.current),select(extent([[0,0],[innerWidthHisto, innerHeightHisto]])));
    }, [xScaleHist, innerWidthHisto, innerHeightHisto, brushFilterFunc, xValue, xFormat]);

    const [histRangeFilterLabel, setHistRangeFilterLabel] = useState(null);

    return (
        <>
            <svg width={widthHisto} height={heightHisto}>
                <g transform={`translate(${marginHisto.left},${marginHisto.top})`}>
                    <AxisBottom
                        xScale={xScaleHist}
                        innerHeight={innerHeightHisto}
                        tickFormat={xFormat}
                        xTicks={5}
                    />
                    <AxisLeft
                        yScale={yScaleBinned}
                        innerWidth={innerWidthHisto}
                        yFormat={format("")}
                        yTicks={3}
                    />
                    <HistoMarks
                        binnedData={binnedData}
                        yScaleBinned={yScaleBinned}
                        xScale={xScaleHist}
                        histoHeight={innerHeightHisto}
                        tickFormat={xFormat}
                    />
                    <g ref={brushRef} />
                </g>
            </svg>
            <span className="hist-range">{histRangeFilterLabel} </span>
        </>
    )
}
```

Thank you for reading and may helping :-)

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet or a fiddle with some data?